# Rejection Sampling reasoning for Lattice Based Signatures

Tags: lattice-crypto

I'm new to lattices.
According to [Lattice Signatures and Bimodal Gaussians](https://eprint.iacr.org/2013/383.pdf) in the Rejection Sampling section.
In Schnorr, GQ you can simply commit to $y$, use it to hide a secret key $s$.
But this doesn't work in lattices. You need to hide the secret key with a small $y$. Turns out, a lot of old lattice-based signatures leaked a part of the secret keys. Instead, we must choose y from a narrow distribution and then perform rejection sampling so that $s$ is not leaked when we add $y$ to it.

Now:

1. What does there mean to be a *narrow* distribution?
2. What does it mean for $y$ to be *small*?
3. Why is this a problem in lattices specifically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Narrow means that, with high probability, the ouput of the distribution is is small.
2. Small is meant in the sense of the Euclidean norm of a vector in the Euclidean space $\mathbb R^n$. More concretly, $v$ is informally said small to mean $\|v\| \leq B$ for some value $B > 0$ chosen large enough for a given scheme to work out, but small enough for the lattice problem SIS to remain hard.
3. It is not a problem outside lattice based crypto because in a finite group $G$, if $x \in G$ is uniform, so is $x+c$. We can't simply do that over an unbounded space such as $\mathbb R^n$.